# How would I match all data between 2 symbols with Regex?

Tags: regex, notepad++, emeditor

I'm trying to find all data (including and after) a dash (-) appears, only up to the first delimiter which is a colon.

Example data:

```
Input:
bart23-testaccount@test.test:Test:Test:Test

Desired output:
bart23:Test:Test:Test
```

I've done some research and found this regex, but it's not fit for purpose `-(.*):`

My purpose is for thousands of lines which are all in various types of order, however the purpose remains the same, highlight all text between the `-` and the first `:` (which I will then proceed to delete). I will be using Notepad++

I can answer any questions or make my post more specific if need be, it's kind of hard to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Notepad++ you can use regex find/replace. Look for:

```
^([^-]+)-[^:]+(:.*)$
```

which captures everything up to the first `-` in group 1, and everything after (and including) the first `:` in group 2, and replace with

```
\1\2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Notepad++, without any capture group:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `-[^:]+`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
-           # an hyphen (by default, the first one in a line)
[^:]+       # 1 or more not colon
```

**Result for given example:**

```
bart23:Test:Test:Test
```

**Screen capture:**

[image]